# AS3 - Referencing the Stage after Preloader Implementation

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, flash-builder, preloader, stage

Ive just finished the basic structure of a little game and saved the simple preloader till last. Silly me.

After numerous tutorials I found this one that worked for me - [Pre Loader in Flash Builder](http://fortheloss.org/how-to-preloader-in-flash-builder-4-7/)

The preloader works and the game is on the stage, but freezes instantly. Any reference to the **stage** in my LevelOne code throws up errors.  **error #1009: cannot access a property or method of a null object reference.**

Before implementing the Preloader, my Application Class (RookiesGame) was used as a level switcher. Each level is contained  in a Sprite. RookiesGame starts by adding LevelOne to stage, then once player completes it, RookiesGame removes LevelOne and adds LevelTwo to stage etc.

The level classes reference the stage with the **_stage** variable.

Since Ive been learning this structure, the preloader becoming the application class and RookiesGame becoming just another class has really confused me. Shouldn’t the _stage var still work? Is it okay to keep RookiesGame as a level switcher?

Anyway main problem is referencing the stage from the Level Classes.

Current code:

**Preloader Class**

Works fine, game starts.

```
package
{
    import flash.display.DisplayObject;
    import flash.display.Shape;
    import flash.display.Sprite;
    import flash.display.StageAlign;
    import flash.display.StageScaleMode;
    import flash.events.Event;
    import flash.utils.getDefinitionByName;

    [SWF(width="650", height="450", backgroundColor="#FFFFFF", frameRate="60")]

    public class Preloader extends Sprite
    {
        // Private
        private var _preloaderBackground:Shape
        private var _preloaderPercent:Shape;
        private var _checkForCacheFlag:Boolean = true;
        // Constants
        private static const MAIN_CLASS_NAME:String = "RookiesGame";

        public function Preloader()
        {
            trace("Preloader: Initialized.")
            addEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, onAddedToStage);
        }

        public function dispose():void
        {
            trace("Preloader: Disposing.")
            removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, onEnterFrame);
            if (_preloaderBackground)
            {
                removeChild(_preloaderBackground);
                _preloaderBackground = null;
            }
            if (_preloaderPercent)
            {
                removeChild(_preloaderPercent);
                _preloaderPercent = null;
            }
        }

        // Private functions

        private function onAddedToStage(e:Event):void
        {
            trace("Preloader: Added to stage.");
            removeEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, onAddedToStage);
            stage.scaleMode = StageScaleMode.SHOW_ALL;
            stage.align = StageAlign.TOP_LEFT;
            addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, onEnterFrame);
        }

        private function onEnterFrame(e:Event):void
        {
            if (_checkForCacheFlag == true)
            {
                _checkForCacheFlag = false;
                if (root.loaderInfo.bytesLoaded >= root.loaderInfo.bytesTotal)
                {
                    trace("Preloader: No need to load, all " + root.loaderInfo.bytesTotal + " bytes are cached.");
                    finishedLoading();
                }
                else
                    beginLoading();
            }
            else
            {
                if (root.loaderInfo.bytesLoaded >= root.loaderInfo.bytesTotal)
                {
                    trace("Preloader: Finished loading all " + root.loaderInfo.bytesTotal + " bytes.");
                    finishedLoading();
                }
                else
                {
                    var percent:Number = root.loaderInfo.bytesLoaded / root.loaderInfo.bytesTotal;
                    updateGraphic(percent);
                    trace("Preloader: " + (percent * 100) + " %");
                }
            }
        }

        private function beginLoading():void
        {
            // Might not be called if cached.
            // ------------------------------
            trace("Preloader: Beginning loading.")
            _preloaderBackground = new Shape()
            _preloaderBackground.graphics.beginFill(0x333333)
            _preloaderBackground.graphics.lineStyle(2,0x000000)
            _preloaderBackground.graphics.drawRect(0,0,200,20)
            _preloaderBackground.graphics.endFill()

            _preloaderPercent = new Shape()
            _preloaderPercent.graphics.beginFill(0xFFFFFFF)
            _preloaderPercent.graphics.drawRect(0,0,200,20)
            _preloaderPercent.graphics.endFill()

            addChild(_preloaderBackground)
            addChild(_preloaderPercent)
            _preloaderBackground.x = _preloaderBackground.y = 10
            _preloaderPercent.x = _preloaderPercent.y = 10
            _preloaderPercent.scaleX = 0
        }

        private function updateGraphic(percent:Number):void
        {
            // Might not be called if cached.
            // ------------------------------
            _preloaderPercent.scaleX = percent
        }

        private function finishedLoading():void
        {
            var RookiesGame:Class = getDefinitionByName(MAIN_CLASS_NAME) as Class;

            if (RookiesGame == null)
                throw new Error("Preloader: There is no class \"" + MAIN_CLASS_NAME + "\".");

            var main:DisplayObject = new RookiesGame() as DisplayObject;
            if (main == null)
                throw new Error("Preloader: The class \"" + MAIN_CLASS_NAME + "\" is not a Sprite or MovieClip.");

            addChild(main);
            dispose();
        }
    }
}
```

**RookiesGame Class (used to be application class)**

Any references to the stage threw up #1009 error, which stopped when I changed stage.addChild to *this*.addChild

Ive not got to the level switch handler yet with the preloader, so I dont know how stage.focus will work either!

```
package
{
        import flash.display.MovieClip;
        import flash.display.Sprite;
        import flash.events.Event;

        public class RookiesGame extends Sprite
        {
            private var _levelOne:LevelOne;
            private var _levelTwo:LevelTwo;

                public function RookiesGame()
                {
                _levelOne = new LevelOne(stage);
                _levelTwo = new LevelTwo(stage);
                this.addChild(_levelOne); 
                        this.addEventListener("levelOneComplete",levelTwoSwitchHandler);                        
                }
                private function levelTwoSwitchHandler(event:Event):void
                {
                        this.removeChild(_levelOne);
                    _levelOne = null;
                    this.addChild(_levelTwo);
                        stage.focus = stage;            

                }
            }
}
```

**LevelOne Class**

Lots of #1009 errors. Anything referencing the stage.

Class is huge so I'll highlight problem chunks.

The #1009 error when referencing stage, adding the keyboard listeners.

```
_stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, keyDownHandler);
_stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_UP, keyUpHandler);
```

Also #1009 when referencing stage to check stage Boundaries. Cant just change *stage.* to *this.* anymore.

```
private function checkStageBoundaries(gameObject:MovieClip):void
        {
            if (gameObject.x < 50)
            {
                gameObject.x = 50;
            }
            if (gameObject.y < 50)
            {
                gameObject.y = 50;
            }
            if (gameObject.x + gameObject.width > _stage.stageWidth - 50)
            {
                gameObject.x = _stage.stageWidth - gameObject.width - 50;
            }
            if (gameObject.y + gameObject.height > _stage.stageHeight - 50)
            {
                gameObject.y = _stage.stageHeight - gameObject.height - 50;
            }
        }
```

I reference _stage later in the program to remove the event listeners. Thats it.

```
_stage.removeEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, keyDownHandler);
_stage.removeEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_UP, keyUpHandler);
```

How can I reference the stage, without these errors and keep RookiesGame as the level switcher.

**LevelOne Class Structure**

To show how I use(d) _stage.

```
package
{
       //import classes

        public class LevelOne extends Sprite
        {
        //Declare the variables to hold the game objects

        //A variable to store the reference to the stage from the application class
        private var _stage:Object;


        public function LevelOne(stage:Object)
            {
                _stage = stage; 
                this.addEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, addedToStageHandler);
            }
            private function addedToStageHandler(event:Event):void
            {
                startGame();
                this.removeEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, addedToStageHandler);
            }
            private function startGame():void
            {
            //Includes _stage references that mess everything up.
            }
            private function levelCleared():void
            {
            //When Level finished, dispatch event to tell RookiesGame to switch levels.
            dispatchEvent(new Event("levelOneComplete", true));
            }
    }         
}
```

Sorry if thats confusing, but if you can help me reference the stage via LevelOne and RookiesGame classes, It would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are passing in a null `stage` to `LevelOne` from your `RookiesGame` class. Whenever you instantiate a `RookiesGame` the constructor will run first, it has not been added to the display list yet so its inherited reference to `stage` is `null`. What you need to do is add an event listener for `ADDED_TO_STAGE` in the `RookiesGame` class:

```
package
{
    import flash.display.MovieClip;
    import flash.display.Sprite;
    import flash.events.Event;

    public class RookiesGame extends Sprite
    {
        private var _levelOne:LevelOne;
        private var _levelTwo:LevelTwo;

            public function RookiesGame()
            {
                addEventListener( Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, onAdded );                        
            }
            //added to stage event
            private function onAdded( e:Event ):void {
                removeEventListener( Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, onAdded );
                _levelOne = new LevelOne(stage);
                _levelTwo = new LevelTwo(stage);
                this.addChild(_levelOne); 
                this.addEventListener("levelOneComplete",levelTwoSwitchHandler);
            }

            ...
        }
```

Also if you are using `addChild()` call for `LevelOne` as in `addChild(_levelOne)` it has its own reference to `stage` after it's been added to the display list, you do not need to create a `_stage` variable for those classes if you are adding them to the display list.

Also you have the listener for `ADDED_TO_STAGE` in `LevelOne`, where the `stage` variable would have no longer been null, so you can remove your class variable `_stage` entirely.

Comment: Thanks that worked great. You're right about removing the _stage variable entirely too. The text Ive been learning from uses the _stage var and ADDED_TO_STAGE? Strange. Thanks again!